# How to bold face Devanagari font when using LuaLaTeX?

Tags: luatex, fontspec, bold, hindi, devanagari

When using LuaLaTeX with the following config for the Polyglossia package, the bold face of fonts doesn't render when using `\textbf{}`.

```
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hindi}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontscript{Devanagari}{deva,dev2}
\newfontface{\hindi}[Script=Devanagari,Renderer=Harfbuzz]{Nakula}
\setmainfont{Nakula}
```

I am not familiar the `fontspec` package. Could you tell me how I could make the bold face work?

Comment: Please always post complete examples which can be compiled and tested by users trying to help you here. Posting a small snippet from your preamble doesn't help.

Answer (score 3):

LaTeX doesn't print characters in bold if the font isn't available in bold weight. I didn't find Nakula-Bold.ttf/otf anywhere. If you can find it your issue will be solved easily. You don't need to load `fontspec` if you load `polyglossia`. The latter loads the former anyways. You first set the main font of the document as Times New Roman, at the end you change it to Nakula which means the former command has no effect now. Also if you want to use Nakula as the "main font", there is no need to load it as a "new font". Devanagari script is already defined by `fontspec` and thus you don't need `\newfontscript` also. Thus I think four lines of your code can be omitted. See the following example. I prefer the `babel` package and follow [these guidelines](https://latex3.github.io/babel/guides/locale-hindi.html).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hindi,provide=*]{babel}
\babelprovide{hindi}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\baloo[%
  Script=Devanagari,%
  Renderer=Harfbuzz%
]{Baloo2}
\newfontfamily\nakula[%
  Script=Devanagari,%
  Renderer=Harfbuzz%
]{Nakula}

\begin{document}
\verb|\textbf| works with Baloo2: {\baloo नमस्ते}, \textbf{\baloo नमस्ते}

but doesn't with Nakula: {\nakula नमस्ते}, \textbf{{\nakula नमस्ते}}
\end{document}
```

There are many other fonts with all the weights you need. My personal favorites are Baloo2 and Mukta by EkType. Both of them are [available](https://ctan.org/pkg/EkType-Tanka) in TeX distributions.